# Why my audio gets distorted in an Android build (Unity3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I have a game in Unity3D, In this game I imported some audio files that are songs, I composed them in a program called Bosca Ceoil, save it as .wav, then, I imported and edited them in Audacity, as the same, saved them as .wav, and finally imported them to Unity.

The thing here is that these audios sound distorted, like if they were to loud and kind of a robotic effect.

So I turned off the Doppler effect in the Audio Source and also in the project settings.

Its a little weird because this audios only gets distorted when I build it in my Android device, in my computer, in the editor works fine.

Also, the distorted parts are only specific ones, curiosly the parts with drums dont get distorted, all the others yes do, and this is very strange because the distorted parts are not loud.

Comment: I'm not sure yet how this applies to C#-- But have you tested the files **before** importing them to anything? Perhaps the imports are causing the distortion.

Comment: Yes, I've played the audio before

Answer (score 0):

Unity does not have a built-in compressor, which means any waveforms that add up to over 1 will distort. (This will invariably happen if you are importing high-quality and/or loud clips.)

You can use the Audio Manager in Unity’s Editor to tweak the maximum Volume of all sounds played in the scene.

but if it works in the editor it could be the below

If you are experiencing issues with sound quality, volume, distortion etc and you are running Android 5.x Lollipop please try disabling 'Nuplayer' from the developer settings. This is an experimental player Google introduced to Android and is known to cause some issues.